# Rails 3. Don't validate nested attributes if all left blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a form with nested attributes. I'm registering a student to a school and the student can have many emergency contacts.

```
class EmergencyContact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :full_name, :relationship, :mobile_phone, :student_id
  belongs_to :student

  validates :full_name, :presence => true
  validates :relationship, :presence => true

end
```

So I have a form to register the student and then 3 rows to enter the emergency contacts. Similar to the following (this is an oversimplified version of course...

```
Student Name: _____________

Emergency Contacts
------------------------------------------
| Name         | Relationship             |
------------------------------------------
|              |                          |
------------------------------------------
|              |                          |
------------------------------------------
|              |                          |
------------------------------------------
```

If I only enter 2 emergency contacts, then I will get validation error that the name of the emergency contact can't be blank. **How can I make it NOT validate if all the fields in the form for that particual emergency contact are all blank?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume you have accepts_nested_attributes set up in your Student model. You need to add a :reject_if proc. It will ignore the row if the proc evaluates to true.

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many                      :emergency_contacts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :emergency_contacts, 
                                :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:full_name].blank? }
end
```

You could modify it to something like `lambda { |a| a[:name].blank? && a[:relationship].blank? }`, etc. as your needs dictate.

Comment: how to generate a form validation error when reject_if is true so that user can correct the error? It just not save anything and report validation error to user.

Comment: Try `accepts_nested_attributes_for :relations` and then on the next line, `validates_associated :relations` You shouldn't need the `:reject_if` option in this case. See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated for more info.

Comment: @niiru Talking about nested resources, what if I need to ***ignore the row if all the fields are blank*** but if ***any field is filled, validate the hole resource*** and show errors to user.

Answer (score 7):

You could also modify it to something more generic like

```
proc { |attributes| 
    attributes.delete :_destroy
    attributes.reject { |key, value| value.blank? }.empty?
}
```

**EDIT**

You can also do this in an easiest way

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :emergency_contacts, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

You can find some documentation here : [http://api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#method-i-accepts_nested_attributes_for)